# What's the name of this NES game with a yellow child as the playable character?

Tags: game-identification, nes

I recently came across a video which briefly showed a few seconds of gameplay from a game I played as a child:

[image: Screenshot of game]

There was no mention of what its name is, and I can't remember it myself. I'd love to play it again, or at least watch more of it.

The kid(?) in yellow is the playable character.

Comment: @Matthew: The video I mentioned can be found [here](http://cinemassacre.com/2009/01/27/milons-secret-castle-2/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Google Images' relatively new [image-matching feature](http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdptm.png), which I fed the screenshot you provided to, apparently it's Disney's [Adventures in the Magic Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_in_the_Magic_Kingdom).

Here's another gameplay video:

Comment: That's, with no doubt, the game I had in mind. I've never heard of the image-matching feature before, I'll be sure to check it out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes I can confirm it's Adventures in the Magic Kingdom. I just played through and beat it.

Comment: I can confirm that from my memory of the game. Probably the second hardest Disney game after _Duck Tails_.

Comment: Haha I tried the same search and got no results.  Awesome :P

Comment: @Matthew Read: Did you click the camera icon in the Google Images search box before pasting the stack.imgur URL?

Comment: Yep, it must've been broken for a bit the other day.